# Datetime Format Method not working as desired

Tags: apex, datetime, method

I came across a weird scenario. The format method is replacing month with '00' in its result.

A portion of my code: (Executed Anonymously to test)

```
System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****m.date_approved__c***'+m.date_approved__c);

if(m.date_approved__c!=null) {
    System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****year***'+m.date_approved__c.year());
    System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****month***'+m.date_approved__c.month());
    System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****day***'+m.date_approved__c.day());

    Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(m.date_approved__c.year(), m.date_approved__c.month(),m.date_approved__c.day());
    System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****date before formatting***'+dt);

    approveddate = dt.Format('mm/dd/yyyy');
}

System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****approveddate***'+approveddate);`
```

Debug Results

> 11:24:31.35 (85764301)|USER_DEBUG|[138]|ERROR|****m.date_approved__c***2016-06-24 00:00:00
>   11:24:31.35 (85826327)|USER_DEBUG|[140]|ERROR|****year***2016
>   11:24:31.35 (85873389)|USER_DEBUG|[141]|ERROR|****month***6
>   11:24:31.35 (85950679)|USER_DEBUG|[142]|ERROR|****day***24
>   11:24:31.35 (86109856)|USER_DEBUG|[144]|ERROR|****date before formatting***2016-06-24 07:00:00
>   11:24:31.35 (86188235)|USER_DEBUG|[149]|ERROR|****approveddate***00/24/2016

I tested this method separately, and it is working fine.

```
MyObj__c m = [select id, date_approved__c from MyObj__C WHERE Id = 'a033900000EU9LN'];
Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(m.date_approved__c.year(), m.date_approved__c.month(),m.date_approved__c.day());

System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'****date before formatting***'+dt);
System.Debug(logginglevel.error,'*****testing format method******'+dt.Format('MM/dd/yyyy'));`
```

Debug result:

> 11:27:41.1 (6791165)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|****date before formatting***2016-06-24 07:00:00
>   11:27:41.1 (6886491)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|ERROR|*****testing format method******06/24/2016

**I used the same record in both the cases**

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Java [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). These format strings are *case-sensitive*, as different casings of the same letter can have different meanings.

> `m` outputs `Minute in hour`.
>
> `M` outputs `Month in year`.

So make sure you use `MM` when trying to output the *month*, and only use `mm` if you are trying to output the *minutes*.

---

#### SimpleDateFormat patterns

**letter - description - type - example**

- **`G`** - Era designator - [Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text) - `AD`
- **`y`** - Year  - [Year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year) - `1996`; `96`
- **`M`** - Month in year  - [Month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month) - `July`; `Jul`; `07`
- **`w`** - Week in year  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `27`
- **`W`** - Week in month  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `2`
- **`D`** - Day in year  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `189`
- **`d`** - Day in month  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `10`
- **`F`** - Day of week in month  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `2`
- **`E`** - Day in week  - [Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text)  - `Tuesday`; `Tue`
- **`a`** - Am/pm marker  - [Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text) - `PM`
- **`H`** - Hour in day (0-23)  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `0`
- **`k`** - Hour in day (1-24)  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `24`
- **`K`** - Hour in am/pm (0-11)  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `0`
- **`h`** - Hour in am/pm (1-12)  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `12`
- **`m`** - Minute in hour  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `30`
- **`s`** - Second in minute  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `55`
- **`S`** - Millisecond  - [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number)  - `978`
- **`z`** - Time zone  - [General time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) - `Pacific Standard Time`; `PST`; `GMT-08:00`
- **`Z`** - Time zone  - [RFC 822 time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) - `-0800`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that I was using both mm and MM. I thought I was using mm in both the cases.

Comment: It's a good document to bookmark. Or at least to remember how to look up.

Comment: Yes...I'm  going through that document now :)